# Change the custom component attribute value dynamically from javascript

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a custom component in my visualforce page, it requires an attribute :

```
<c:myCustomComponent id="myCC" attr='Some value'></c:myCustomComponent>
```

and I want to change the attribute value dynamically from javascript.
I tried  `getElementById('myCC').setAttribute('other value')`, but it doesn't seem to work, and the DOM doesn't have a reference for the custom component Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access visualforce elements with  javascript directly by id you have entered, because the real id of generated dom element looks different. 
I use jquery for that, it is very easy:

```salesforce
<c:MyComponent id="myCC" />

<script>
    jQuery("[id$=myCC]").hide();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks you very much mast0r, it worked, i learned something new.

Comment: Just a remark mast0r, custom components are not rendered with their attributes, so even if you can get the component by id from DOM, you can't change the attributes value :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **document**.getElementById('myCC').setAttribute(**'value'**, 'other value');

And not use the attribute 'attr'.

Check this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wkJck/

Comment: thank you for the answer rednaw, actually i used the method the same way as you, i didn't write it the proper way in the question, my problem is that the dom does not find the id attribute of the custom component. thank you again

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Did you check my jsfiddle? You can always check what your selector returns using console.log(document.getElementById('myCC'); What's the result of that?

Comment: i get null :( , i think the getElementById doesn't work for custom components caus i tried it on the surrounding div it works fine, but the component it's always a null...

Comment: Did the fiddle work for you? Did you try it in different browsers? Is the element with this id unique on your page?

Comment: yep it worked fine, tried it on mozilla and chrome, visualforce renderes the custom components as a span something like :    <span id="j_id0:blockPrendreRdv:cmp09">, it's rendered without attributes, i think when i tried to get it by id i was totally on the wrong way, i don't know what u think of this, the id is also unique thx

Comment: Oh, I'm actually not quite familiar with Visualforce, but mast0r seems to have a possible solution for you.

Comment: thank you very much rednaw, the solution of mast0r worked, than you again cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to define first your value attribute, then you can access and change it by javascript.

e.g. :

component **definition**

```
    <apex:attribute name="myValue" description="This is the value for the component."  type="String" required="true"/>
```

accessing value by **visualforce**

```
<c:myComponent myValue="Some value" id="myCC"/>
```

accessing and changing by **javascript**

```
document.getElementById('myCC').value ='other value' ;
```

Read a complete example in the [official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_comp_cust_elements_attributes.htm)

Comment: Thanks martin, I've read in the doc that the custom components have a default attribute : the 'id' attribute, and i don't need to declare it inside the cComponent code, however, it doesn't work properly when i try to call it, seem strange to me, have you used it before, thank you very much.